# "Whom" or "who" where the referent is both subject and object?

Tags: subjects, objects, whom

I understand there has been so much on this topic but I am still confused. I get that if the person is the subject it is *who* and anything else is *whom.*
However, I'm really struggling to work out this rule for the following sentence:

> The scope of which his account of morality applies to is therefore restricted to those *whom/who* the ‘notion of justification to a being of that kind makes sense.’

Should it be *who* or *whom*? I can't work out the subject and object.

Comment: That entire sentence makes no sense whatsoever and is completely ungrammatical, so I don’t blame you for not being able to figure out whether it’s the subject or not. What is the sentence trying to say? And why is a random part of it in quotes? If we simplify it to simpler main clauses, we get: “The scope [that his account of morality applies to of] is restricted to some people. These people the ‘notion of justification of a being of that kind makes sense’.” That is more obviously nonsensical.

Comment: It would be extremely hard to understand without any context as it's part of a complex Philosophy essay. The quotation is from a Philosopher which explains the scope which his account of morality applies to.

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact that there are either words missing or words that shouldn’t be there. The sentence is ungrammatical, unless _the ‘notion of justification of a being of that kind makes sense’_ is supposed to act like some kind of very complex and bizarre verb.

Comment: ok, I'll have a look and try and work out exactly what I am trying to say. Thank you.

Comment: Based on your first comment, I’m guessing the first _of_ should go. I’m also going to guess that there should be a _to_ after _those_, and that the quotes are there because you’re citing a specific wording from a text, but put the end quote in the wrong place. Doing that gives, with more natural wording: _“The scope which his account of morality applies to is therefore restricted to those to whom the ‘notion of justification to a being of that kind’ makes sense”_. That sentence makes sense, and also makes it clear that _whom_ is the object of the preposition _to_ and therefore not a subject.

Comment: @Janus: I may be mistaken, but it seems to me the sentence is valid (although maybe a bit clumsy) if we assume some minor (transcription?) errors. The third word *(**of**)* shouldn't be there, and there should be a ***to*** before ***whom***. Plus the closing quote for **‘notion of justification to a being of that kind’** is in the wrong place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The same conclusion I reached after a few read-throughs. Those three errors were just confusing enough to completely entangle the entire thing into nonsense to me at first.

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence, I am a very messy philosopher. Thank you Janus for re-stating the correct sentence in full and a special thanks to @FumbleFingers for kindly wording my incompetence rather than saying my 'entire sentence makes no sense whatsoever!'

Comment: @philosophyislife: I implicitly answered the specific question when I said *there should be a **to** before **whom*** above. But note that increasing numbers of native speakers just use ***who*** in all contexts anyway, so it's a bit pedantic to say one is right and the other is wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But OP is writing for an audience which insists on the who/whom distinction, and in a register in which the distinction is useful.

Comment: @StoneyB: Absolutely. The fact that OP wants to know which is "correct" implies that perspective. Personally, I almost never use *whom* in speech nowadays, but I'd normally "toe the line" in any remotely formal written context.

Answer (score 2):

Note how the original is constructed:

> Neither of these objections applies to the version of contractualism that I am defending. The general specification of the scope of morality which it implies seems to me to be this: morality applies to a being if the notion of justification to a being of that kind makes sense.

The author is dealing with some pretty complicated thoughts here; but he has managed this fairly gracefully<sup>†</sup> by breaking his argument into easily processed chunks.

1. First, he divides it into two stages: **a.** “What I'm talking about: I'm going to specify the scope of morality [with some necessary hedges]”, and **b.** “What I have to say about it: this is the scope”.
2. In stage **b.** he redefines *scope* as an active verb, *applies*, and cunningly employs a conditional construction to distinguish **b1.** the act of applying morality from **b2.** the entities to which morality may be applied—taking care, however, to knit the two together by repetition of the term *being*. This is critical: because that separation allows him to use the preposition *to* for the complement of two different lexemes, *applies* and *justification*, without confusion.

Now you should be able to see where your attempt at a paraphrase has tripped you up.

1. In your subject you have tried to embrace both *scope of morality* and *morality applies to*—which are ***the same thing***: the *scope* does not *apply to* beings: the *scope* ***is*** the beings. Consequently you get your prepositions (*of*, *to*) and their objects tangled up.
2. In the object of *restricted to* you have recast the first *being* as a plural *those*, and defined that with a relative *who/whom* which has ***no distinct syntactic role*** to play in what follows. You are trying to relativize an entity which plays two different roles. Moreover, your prepositions are all cattywhompus because that entity stands as the object of two different *to*s (in addition to the *to* of your *restricted to*!), and you have lost the conditional construction which distinguishes them. (Even if you had kept the conditional construction you would still need another pronoun; see the comments to  [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/153626/24489) by our syntax guru John Lawler.)

It would be much simpler to let Scanlon speak for himself:

> Scanlon restricts his account of morality: “morality applies to a being if the notion of justification to a being of that kind makes sense”.

---

<sub><sup>†</sup>I have some very minor cavils. I'd handle the first clause with fewer nouns, thus: "It seems to me that the scope of morality which it implies may be generally specified thus:...". And *justification to* is tricky; it seems at first glance to be an error because it is immediately *after* this point that Scanlon explains what it means. I would bracket it somehow: *justification-to* or *'justification to'*.</sub>